# How to set VideoView delay in Android Studio for live video playback from a URL?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application using Android Studio and I am using VideoView to play a live video directly from a URL. However, I am experiencing stability issues with the video playback and I would like to adjust the delay of the VideoView to make it more stable.

```
videoview1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
      videoview1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(_map.get("link").toString()));
    videoview1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(_map.get("link").toString()));
videoview1.start();
```

Comment: Hi there, please provide more details about the problem